# Oracle Triggers not inserting latest records into tables

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, database-trigger

I have `TABLE_1` that is parent table of these records which is in `SCHEMA_1` and populating from JAVA/Node.js application on transaction. 
Also have below trigger `(SCHEMA_1.TRIGGER_CALL_SP_OF_SCHEMA_2)` on same `SCHEMA_1` and calling another Stored procedure for populate to another `TABLE_2` which is in `SCHEMA_2` on the basis of Table_1 transactions.

Trigger:

```
create or replace trigger SCHEMA_1.TRIGGER_CALL_SP_OF_SCHEMA_2
  AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT OR DELETE ON SCHEMA_1.TABLE_1
  REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
  FOR EACH ROW
  DECLARE
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
    SCHEMA_2.SP_OF_SCHEMA_2(:NEW.RECORD_ID);
    commit;
  EXCEPTION   WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RAISE;
END;
```

Stored Procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SCHEMA_2.SP_OF_SCHEMA_2(P_RECORD_ID NUMBER ) AS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM SCHEMA_2.TABLE_2 WHERE RECORD_ID = P_RECORD_ID;           
    FOR rec IN (SELECT RECORD_ID, COL2, COL3, COL4  from SCHEMA_1.TABLE_1 where RECORD_ID = P_RECORD_ID)
    LOOP
         INSERT INTO SCHEMA_2.TABLE_2 (RECORD_ID, COL2, COL3, COL4) VALUES(rec.RECORD_ID, rec.COL2, rec.COL3,rec.COL4 );
   END LOOP;
 COMMIT;
END;
```

So the problem is in `Table_2` which don't have always latest records.
Eg: When first record_Id inserted into Table_1 but in Table_2 there is no any entry.
When second time with same records_id inserted with another values in Table_1 but in Table_2 only last record_id with details inserted.(again not latest entry). Below are records sample: (Note - No any PK available in both the tables.)

Table_1

```
+------------+-------+----------+---------+
| RECORD_ID  |  COL2 |   COL3   |  COL4   |
+------------+-------+----------+---------+
|          1 |   101 | abc      |  insert |
+------------+-------+----------+---------+
```

Table_2

```
+------------+-------+----------+------+
| RECORD_ID  |  COL2 |   COL3   | COL4 |
+------------+-------+----------+------+
```

Table_1

```
+------------+-------+----------+---------+
| RECORD_ID  |  COL2 |   COL3   |  COL4   |
+------------+-------+----------+---------+
|          1 |   101 | abc      |  insert |
|          1 |   102 | xyz      |  insert |
+------------+-------+----------+---------+
```

Table_2

```
+------------+-------+----------+---------+
| RECORD_ID  |  COL2 |   COL3   |  COL4   |
+------------+-------+----------+---------+
|          1 |   101 | abc      |  insert |
+------------+-------+----------+---------+
```

Is this b'cze of any database commit sequence or any transaction related issues or any other possible scenario? How can achieve that to keep Table_2 update always. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: your procedure loops through (SELECT RECORD_ID, COL2, COL3, COL4  from SCHEMA_1.TABLE_1 where RECORD_ID = P_RECORD_ID), are you sure this returns any value?

Comment: neither in the trigger nor in the procedure use `commit`. It may be an overkill for the transaction integrity.

Answer (score 0):

The trigger has an autonomous transaction.

So the insert/update/delete that fires the trigger is in a separate transaction to the call of the procedure in the trigger.

Transactions can only view **committed** changes from others.

So the transaction in the trigger can't see the row you've inserted!

```
create table t1 (
  c1 int
);
create table t2 (
  c1 int
);

create or replace trigger trig
after insert on t1
for each row
declare
  pragma autonomous_transaction;
begin
  insert into t2
    select * from t1
    where  c1 = :new.c1;

  dbms_output.put_line ( 'Rows added: ' || sql%rowcount );
  commit;
end;
/

insert into t1 values ( 1 );

Rows added: 0
commit;
insert into t1 values ( 1 );

Rows added: 1

select * from t2;

        C1
----------
         1
```

As referring to `table_1` without the autonomous transaction will raise a mutating trigger error (ORA-04091), you'll need to rethink this process.